# What are the advantages/Disadvantages to clip and clipless pedals?

Tags: road-bike, pedals, clipless, toe-straps-clips

I`m fairly new to the sport and I see the people in my town half have clips and the other clipless pedals. Is there any advantage to using clipless  competitively or recreationally?

Comment: You're clear that clipless pedals still have you clipped into the pedal, right?

Comment: @Batman yes, clipless uses cleats to attach to the bike and the toe straps you slide a tennis shoe in. I understand how they work but is it worth it to switch from straps to clipless?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of one of the existing questions. [advantages of different clipless](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2690/what-are-the-advantages-of-the-different-clipless-systems) or [straps over clipless](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1628/is-there-any-advantage-to-using-pedal-straps-over-clipless-pedals) for example.

Comment: This has to be one of the more common questions on this site.  Stackexchange's search function is really good - try it out.
For me, cleats "did nothing" till I went back to flats, and realised that for me its about keeping the foot on the pedal,  not about lifting on the upstroke.